# Kong's flaky rate limiting behavior

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I have deployed some APIs in Azure Kubernetes Service and I have been experimenting with [Kong](https://konghq.com/)  to be able to use some of its features such as rate limiting and IP restriction but it doesn't always work as expected. Here is the plugin objects I use:

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongClusterPlugin
metadata:
  name: kong-rate-limiting-plugin
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
  labels:
    global: 'true'
config:
  minute: 10
  policy: local
  limit_by: ip
  hide_client_headers: true
plugin: rate-limiting

---

apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongClusterPlugin
metadata:
  name: kong-ip-restriction-plugin
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
  labels:
    global: 'true'
config: 
  deny:
  - {some IP}
plugin: ip-restriction
```

The first problem is when I tried to apply these plugins across the cluster by setting the global label to \"true\" as described [here](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/rate-limiting/#enable-the-plugin-globally), I got this error when applying it with kubectl:

```
metadata.labels: Invalid value: "\\\"true\\\"": a valid label must be an empty string or consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyValue',  or 'my_value',  or '12345', regex used for validation is '(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?')
```

The second problem is even though I used KongClusterPlugin and set global to 'true', I still had to add the plugins explicitly to the ingress object for them to work. Here is my ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ing
  annotations:
    konghq.com/plugins: kong-rate-limiting-plugin,kong-ip-restriction-plugin
    konghq.com/protocols: https
    konghq.com/https-redirect-status-code: "301"
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: kong
...
```

And here is my service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-svc
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
...
```

The third problem is by setting limit_by to ip, I expected it to rate-limit per IP, but I noticed it would block all clients when the threshold was hit collectively by the clients. I tried to mitigate that by preserving the client IP and setting externalTrafficPolicy to Local in the service object as I thought maybe the Kubernetes objects weren't receiving the actual client's IP. Now the rate limiting behavior seems to be more reasonable, however sometimes it's as if it's back to its old state and returns HTTP 429 randomly. The other issue I see here is I can set externalTrafficPolicy to Local only when the service type has been set to LoadBalancer or NodePort. I set my service to be of type LoadBalancer which exposes it publicly and seems to be a problem. It would be ironic that using an ingress controller that's supposed to shield the service rather exposes it. Am I missing something here or does this make no sense?

The fourth problem is the IP restriction plugin doesn't seem to be working. I was able to successfully call the APIs from a machine with the IP I put in 'config.deny'.

The fifth problem is the number of times per minute I have to hit the APIs to get a HTTP 429 doesn't match the value I placed in 'config.minute'.

Comment: try adding the database like redis in backend for plugin and test you might see better result maybe

Comment: 1) Have you enabled access logs? Can you see the external IP there? 2) Maybe its only getting the load balancer IP if its behind a load balancer. 3) Try checking my sample [kong task here](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/devops-essentials/tree/main/kubernetes/aws/task-030-kong-ingress-on-eks)

Comment: your fourth problem seems not link.
For the fifth, there is a race condition by design, you can have a little more than expected.
The goal is to protect not to a precise rate

Comment: What is the IP you get, is it the real external ip, or an internal  ? Using an header can be better than using the connection ip